# What to install to use the NVIDIA card

Tags: nvidia, system-installation

I have successfully installed ubuntu on my new machine (dual boot)
(I think I have secure boot activated  just FYI)

What are the next procedures that I should do to fully utilize my NVIDIA card?

I tried doing `nvidia-smi` but the command is not found.

I suppose I should install the NVIDIA drivers and perhaps CUDA??

Comment: Secure Boot should be disabled in BIOS with NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install via System Settings ---> Additional Drivers

(!!! I keep forgetting that I use MATE, which uses this interface... you can also reach this by opening the Software Updater and clicking on Settings)

[image]

Comment: Ok! Done that! (it failed the first time, but now it is done!) nvidia-smi now works! What next? CUDA? CuDNN?